# Search inside pre populated sqlite database in android

Tags: android, sqlite

I am very new to android,
I want to build an app that contains a pre populated sqlite database in its assets folder(fields of database are text only),I want to add text search capability in my app that can search inside my database,my question is that whether I must use FTS3(I am not familiar with it!) or I can easily perform query inside my database?

Comment: once I have same type of app and i did without any such thing FTS3

Comment: This answer can help you to copy database from assets folder 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5086962/adding-your-own-sqlite-database-to-an-android-application/5948819#5948819
and then maybe you can try something like given here for fetching data
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18466787/how-to-use-fts3-in-sqlite

Comment: thanks!I successfully copy database from assets folder to device,Is there any tutorial that shows populating virtual table with pre-loaded database?(All tutorial I have seen related to dictionary example)